# idea behind crime punishment

Tags: prison, crime

What is the idea behind putting people who commited a crime into prison?

What such a state does is an act, that if a person does to a different person, it is called limiting someone's freedom, which is a crime.

So the country basically applies a principle "eye for an eye" by sending people to prison. The idea "eye for an eye" is basically a revenge.

Isn't there a better principle to apply?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

## Principles of sentencing

I question your premise that the country applies an "eye for an eye" principle to sentencing.

In Canada, for example, the declared purposes of sentencing do not include revenge. The purposes of sentencing is listed at [s. 718 of the Criminal Code](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/section-718.html):

> 718 The fundamental purpose of sentencing is to protect society and to contribute, along with crime prevention initiatives, to respect for the law and the maintenance of a just, peaceful and safe society by imposing just sanctions that have one or more of the following objectives:
>
> (a) to denounce unlawful conduct and the harm done to victims or to the community that is caused by unlawful conduct;
>
> (b) to deter the offender and other persons from committing offences;
>
> (c) to separate offenders from society, where necessary;
>
> (d) to assist in rehabilitating offenders;
>
> (e) to provide reparations for harm done to victims or to the community; and
>
> (f) to promote a sense of responsibility in offenders, and acknowledgment of the harm done to victims or to the community.

This is described in more detail in this [Parliamentary research paper](https://lop.parl.ca/sites/PublicWebsite/default/en_CA/ResearchPublications/202006E). It discusses the purposes of sentencing including non-custodial (out-of-prison) sentences.

## Prison abolition / decarceral options

Regardless, many people are imagining and working towards a legal system with less imprisonment. This activism and research is characterized as "decarceral" or "abolitionist." Here is some material about this ("[Intro to Abolition](https://abolitionistfutures.com/intro-to-abolition)", [noprisons.ca](https://noprisons.ca/abolition-syllabus-2022/) and their [Syllabus: "Abolition in So-Called Canada"](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IUm3HUVmk4_EGPsuSuyk8WvV2aq7s5yyIUViQ_T_m9o/edit)).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of the biblical "eye for an eye" was, from very early times, not meant to call for revenge, even though it was (and is) sometimes read like that. It was meant to *restrict* the punishment of the offender and simply meant that the compensation for a lost eye is the (estimated) value of said eye. If somebody accidentally caused someone else to lose an eye, he had to pay a compensation for that. And only a monetary compensation. In other cultures, such an accident would have called for a bloody revenge towards the offender. Details are a lot more complicated and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_for_an_eye).

So even in biblical times, a punishment was not meant as revenge. Not even a death penalty was, as this was (in the Old Testament) meant to "remove the evil from the people".